# Sending contract transaction to non-contract address

Tags: contract-invocation, addresses

What happens if one sends contract transactions to non-contract address (Geth account)? E.g. one writes the transaction to call contract function, but the destination address is geth account?

There kind of transactions doesn't seem to cause out of gas. The transaction goes silently through. However is there a way to detect such a condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If sufficient gas is provided, the transaction will be included in a block.

There is no way to detect the condition: it's like sending Ether to a wrong address.

Sending Ether to a wrong address is a transaction where a snippet of it looks like:

`{to:'...', value:'...'}` (transaction with `value` and no `data`)

The case your describing looks like:

`{to:'...', data:'...'}` (transaction with `data` and no `value`)

---

You can have combinations of a transaction that has both `data` and `value`.

If the `to` account is a contract (it has code), then there are these cases:

- invoked function exists in `to`: the function executes
- invoked function does not exist in `to`: the fallback function is execution
- invoked function does not exist and there is no fallback function: answered by [What happens if you call a non-existent function of another contract that has no fallback function in Solidity?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1416/what-happens-if-you-call-a-non-existent-function-of-another-contract-that-has-no)