# what is the equivalent of encodeFunctionSignature for web3.js version ^0.20.6

Tags: web3js, contract-invocation, erc-721

I want to check if a specific contract deployed at an address is an erc721 contract. I found out that most of the `erc721` contracts should have `safeTransferFrom` function implemented. (except cryptokitties)

So, basically I want to check if `safeTransferFrom` function exists in the contract. I think that this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/50091/42466 would help.

However, I am using an older version of web3.js (0.20.6) and it does not have this function `w3.eth.abi.encodeFunctionSignature(signature);`

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'encodeFunctionSignature' of undefined
```

How can I use it to make it work for my current version of `web3.js`

PS: I found that the latest version of `web3.js` has different function signatures for many functions. So, I would not want to upgrade `web3.js`.

Answer (score 1):

`web3.sha3(signature).substring(0, 10)` should do the trick.